# Can you place an if statement in .ascx layout?

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, ascx

I'm new with working with ASP.net and .ascx, and now I've seen a button that calls a method by 'OnClientClick' So the code looks like this:

`<asp:Button Text="Save" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" OnClientClick="isBusy();"/>`

Now I want that the method only calls at certain definitions declared in the same .ascx file. And thus I thought that an if-statement inside the ascx would work. So I've already tried attempts like `OnClientClick="if(Text.Length <= maxlength) { isBusy(); }` but that caused the line to not respond at all.

Currently I'm wondering if an if-statement in this situation is actually possible.

Comment: "to not respond at all"...you probably had a JavaScript error in your console, so learn to check for those, it can give you a clue as to what's going wrong. You can certainly do `if`s in an ASCX...but within the "OnClientClick", you are writing in JavaScript, because that is code to be executed on the _client_ i.e. browser. Do the variables you mentioned exist in your page's JavaScript? If not you probably got undefined errors. You can also write `if` using your server-side language (C#? VB.NET?) but not quite like that. It might help if you could clarify your actual goal here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is doable.  but you need to make sure your js is correct.

in your question, what is Text.Lengh ?

whatever, if you want block the server side postback, then return false in your onclick JS, that will completely mute the postback event

for example

```
<asp:button runat="server" onclientclick="return false;" />
```

this button will never post back

Comment: `Text.length` as in, I don't want it to trigger the save event if the character cound of the textbox it needs to save is above the allowed text length. about the rest of the question: I don't think I'm understanding the last part. what do you exactly mean with post back?